# Automated Installation Testing on Windows

Tags: healthcheck, automated-testing, automated

I am looking for some software I can work with that will allow me to test that programs were installed and are functioning correctly. Instead of opening each program manually and see it working, I would like something similar to automated unit/integration testing for software development.

I've looked into things like [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) and [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) which seem promising but don't quite meet what I need and they require dependencies to be installed on the system which I am not a huge fan of.

A use case I imagine would be like installing Microsoft Word on a system. I would be able to run this script/program that would open the program itself, open a new document, write some lines to that document, and save the file. This would "prove" that this functionality in Word is working correctly.

Here is essentially what I am looking for:

- Able to open/run programs
- Able to perform tasks in those programs
- Unit test oriented
- Able to output pass/fail for tests
- Able to run on Windows 7 or later
- Can be run off of USB drive alone
- Preferably script oriented (i.e. using Python or lua)

Any ideas or suggestions? I am unaware of industry standards if there are any for this. I am also not completely opposed to writing custom software to integrate with some existing APIs but I would like it to be easy to write and modify tests.

Answer (score 1):

[AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is really helpful for this, and is a scripting language.

It was recommended to me in the past - https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/20049/14701

In addition, you can also use BlueDuck SDA which allows you to create reports and even record your screen - http://blueducksda.sourceforge.net/index.html